# PHP Path Prefixed After Include

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-include

I am using the PhpStorm IDE.

I add the include to the PHP file:

```
include_once 'lib\Zend\Form\Element';
```

And I am expecting to be able to use it as:

```
    new Element();
```

But instead PhpStorm will only let me use it as:

```
    new \Zend\Form\Element();
```

How can I use it without the prefixed path?

Comment: *"And I am expecting to be able to use it as:"* Wrong. You need to use `use` statement for that. You can enable `auto import` in IDE to have FQN (fully qualified name) to be replaced by short names. At any time you can convert FQN into a short by Alt+Enter while having caret in "problematic" place and choosing correct option from there.

Comment: that's not a path. It's a PHP namespace.You'd have to [import](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) that function to use it without any namespace.

Comment: @LazyOne its obviously wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is a difficult task to use any part of Zend without an autoloader, or 10+ lines of config.  Difficult in that you must edit the Zend source to include required files there which is a mess, not future proof, and a bad hack.

Importing and namespacing in my usage file alone does not solve the issue.

**If you have the same problem look into 'composer' and autoloading Zend.**

Answer (score 0):

just including someting in PHP doesn't automatically mean you can skip the namespace prefix.

Including only makes the code available in your current script but you still have to address the class by it's namespace.

```
$var = new \Zend\Form\Element();
```

This is the correct way to address the `Element` constructor in the namespace `Zend\Form`. If you don't want to write \Zend\Form\ every time you can simply use:

```
use Zend\Form\Element;
$var = new Element();
```

You can learn more about namespaces and aliasing here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

In case you still don't understand this:

Including is similar to installing a map on to your gps navigation system. Using the namespace is like defining the zipcode. The constructor is like telling the street and house number to your gps navigation system.